# Why was I2P chosen over Tor for native Monero integration?

Tags: security, kovri, i2p, tor, privacy

Tor is currently much more popular than I2P. Why was I2P chosen (Kovri project) over Tor for native Monero integration?

Comment: short answer: i2p is a more anon tor

Comment: @John I do not think it is proper to say that I2P is just more anonymous than Tor. The answer is more complicated than that.

Comment: @JustinEU4 well, I2P routes better than Tor does as it uses much shorter lived tunnels.  I am indeed over-simplifying my response.

Comment: @JohnHanks I2P uses 10 minute tunnels and Tor uses 10 minute circuits (by default, MaxCircuitDirtiness is 10 minutes). I2P's documentation for "short lived" tunnels needs to be clarified. Also, I2P doesn't "route better" than Tor; it simply routes "differently" since "best effort messaging" works in favor of the network's resilience to downtime. For more info: #kovri-dev on Freenode, Irc2P, or https://slack.monero.com

Comment: @JustinEU4 i2p has parallel load balanced tunnels for the same data instead of having one path.  also all tunnels/circuits in i2p are one way so you need double the nodes.  tor is easier to compromise. i2p is better for anon and better for monero

Answer (score 43, accepted):

There are several advantages where I2P implementation is more suitable over Tor, e.g.

- I2P is significantly faster when routing internal traffic, where Tor is optimized for low-bandwidth clients and high-bandwidth exit nodes,
- I2P doesn't have floodfill routers hardcoded as Tor's directory of servers,
- I2P is a packet-switched network (as opposed to circuit-switched) which makes it more rubust,
- I2P supports UDP, Tor not,
- in I2P all peers assist in running short-lived tunnels, not only client-only peers as in Tor,
- I2P uses API to interact with the network directly, as opposed to SOCKS proxy in Tor,
- I2P aims at being its own lower latency network.

Source: [Why is Monero aiming to integrate I2P?](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/2ti53m/why_is_monero_aiming_to_integrate_i2p/) at reddit